# Hosted static website in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I need help with AWS Host to website.

I hosted my static site following the AWS recomendations. (using S3-bucket, Route-S3).

However, in my site after my domain is appears ".s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com". 
How to do for not appears this after my domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much work, I found it the problem.

Was in create Record Set "A" cheking Alias "Yes" and Alias Target "s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com."

Thanks.